# tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.load_from_file UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, decode, tensorflow-datasets

I am working with tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder and create a dictionary with Ukrainian and Russian symbols.

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

text = ['я тут', 'привет', 'вітання']

tokenizer = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
    text, target_vocab_size=2**15)
tokenizer.save_to_file('tokenizer.tf')
```

But after using

```py
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.load_from_file('tokenizer.tf')
```

I got this error:

```bash
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 81: invalid continuation byte
```

I know the problem is I am working with **Ukrainian and Russian utf-8 symbols**. Strange thing is that this code works in `jupyter notebook` absolutely normal. Somehow it prevents this exception. But I need to run it natively python.

THIS **DID NOT** HELP:

```py
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.load_from_file('tokenizer.tf', encoding='utf-8')
```

Please, help me, what should I code to run this?(

I'm in real trouble because `SubwordTextEncoder` doesn't support anything I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```py
corpus = []
with open('tokenizer.tf.subwords', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   for inx, line in enumerate(f):
       if inx > 1:
          sent = line.lower().strip()
          sent = sent.replace('\n', '')
          sent = re.sub(r"[^а-яА-Я?.!,_]+", " ", sent)
          sent = sent.strip()
          corpus.append(sent)
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder(vocab_list = corpus)
```

The idea was to **load vocabulary as a text file** with encoding parameter and it worked!!!